# make ignoring include directives

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU make and have the following in my Makefile:

```
token_check: token_check.o $(STATIC_LIBRARIES)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c pipeline/*.h compiler/*.h
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -I./pipeline -I./compiler -c $<
```

However, when I run `make`, the command actually run is

```
cc -c -o token_check.o token_check.c
```

and I get the error

```
token_check.c:3:10: fatal error: scanner.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "scanner.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: token_check.o] Error 1
```

scanner.h is contained in the compiler subdirectory.

Why are my `-I` directives being ignored?

EDIT:

I checked and I do have header files in both pipeline and compiler.

What's really weird is, even if I replace the recipe with

```
%.o: %.c pipeline/*.h compiler/*.h
    echo blah
```

and run

```
make token_check.o
```

it still tries to compile the source file and "blah" never gets printed.

Comment: I don't think globs work in GNU Make like that. You need `$(wildcard pipeline/*.h) $(wildcard compiler/*.h)`.

Comment: They do work, BUT they work like shell globs.  That means that if nothing matches them the plain wildcard character will be left.  So, as Renaud says, if either of the two globbing expressions matches no files they'll be left as-is.  So if there are no files that match `pipeline/*.h` then the prerequisite will be the literal string `pipeline/*.h` which probably doesn't exist, so your pattern doesn't match.  The `$(wildcard ...)` function expands to the empty string if the pattern doesn't match, so it may be better for your situation.

Comment: I've added some additional debug information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely make is using its implicit rule, not yours. And most likely it does so because your pattern rule does not apply. One reason could be that you do not have any header file in `pipeline`.

Comment: It turned out I just had a typo.  What I actually had typed was `pipelne/*.h`, not `pipeline/*.h`.